# Office Interop Excel DisplayAlerts = false not working for activation popup

Tags: asp.net, office-interop, excel-2013

In my code I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to generate excel report.

But during the run time an exception is coming as

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800AC472): Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

on line `((xls.Range)worKsheeT.Cells[3, 1]).Font.Bold = true;`

When checked it was found that this error is coming because application is waiting to get response of Activation popup for Excel 2013 which came only after execution of this code.

[image]

As pop clearly shows we have evaluation version of excel on server, but my question is that , is there any chance where we can suppress the pop up from C# and use the evaluation version to generate excel reports??

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use Office interop objects on a server.  Those were designed specifically for client applications and can cause all kinds of problems when used in a server application.  Microsoft does not recommend or support using them in a server application [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Comment: I concur with what Clint says. If you're generating reports server-side you should look into leveraging the Office Open XML file format, rather than automating the application. This is what these file formats were designed for...

Comment: Why don't you just activate the application? There's certainly no way to suppress needing to activate...

Comment: @ClintB..Thanks for sharing. I will surely consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) instead. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.

Or if you need to deal with binary file formats you may consider using third-party components designed for the serve-side execution (for example, Aspose).

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.